# Why can't I grab the current, new and confirm password fields on twitter using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="current_password"]
```

It says this even though the name of the current password field is `"current_password"` on the Twitter password reset page.

Answer (score 0):

I am at this page

```
https://twitter.com/account/reset_password
```

and I see a couple of input boxes with following HTML

```
<input id="password" class="Form-textbox Edge-textbox is-required" type="password" name="password" data-username="cruisepandey" ,="" data-fullname="Cruise Pandey">
```

and

```
<input class="Form-textbox Edge-textbox" type="password" name="password_confirmation">
```

then you can use the below code to send the keys

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password"))).send_keys('Enter your new password here')
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I did not get the `current_password` input box at my end, but you can follow the same way to get the job done.

Comment: what about this page: https://twitter.com/settings/password

Comment: it asked for my login, once I provided it is asking for a password, were you intended to interact with that page ? I see this CSS selector `input[name='password']` which is unique and should work with the above technique.